# Are all the memory Dynamically Allocated by "new" being properly cleared in the following implementation

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator, delete-operator, eigen3

I am in a situation where I need to create a collection of classes which perform computations over Eigen Matrices. The original code is quiet big and complex to explain, so I have implemented a simplified version to explain my problem. I have written the following piece of code. Basically, I need to create a collection of different types of class objects. I plan to achieve this by using a baseClass which is extended by all the classes that need to be part of the collection. A second class named classIterator contains a vector named "classItr" that can store baseClass pointers. The child classes override and implement a function declared in base that is responsible for performing the computations. I delete all the object pointers in classItr using "delete", at the destructor of classIterator. What I want to know is first, whether this implementation is correct and safe and that all the memory allocated by "new" is being freed at the class destructors and second, if there is better and safer way to achieve the same.

The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <Core>

using namespace Eigen;

class baseClass
{
  public:
      MatrixXd m1;
      MatrixXd m2;

      std::string childName;

    baseClass(std::string childName)
    {
      this->childName = childName;
      std::cout << "\n Base Constructor. Child Name : " << this->childName << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~baseClass() 
    {
      std::cout << "\n Base Destructor. Child Name : " << this->childName << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename inputType_1, typename inputType_2>
    void onSetData(MatrixBase<inputType_1> const & mat1, MatrixBase<inputType_2> const & mat2)
    {
      this->m1 = mat1;
      this->m2 = mat2;
    }

    template<typename inputType_1>
    void operator ()(MatrixBase<inputType_1> const & someMat)
    {
      /*
        Some Code Involving "someMat" matrix.
      */

      // Calling the child class implementation of the function.
      someComputation();
    }

    virtual void someComputation() = 0;
};

class firstChild : public baseClass
{
  
  public:

    firstChild() : baseClass("firstChild")
    {
      std::cout << "\n First Child Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~firstChild() 
    { 
      std::cout << "\n First Child Destructor" << std::endl;

      this->m1.resize(0, 0);
      this->m2.resize(0, 0);
    }

    void someComputation() override 
    {
      // Some Computation Using Base classes m1 and m2 go here.
      std::cout << "\n First Child M1 : \n" << this->m1 << "\n M2 : \n" << this->m2 << std::endl;
    }
};

class secondChild : public baseClass
{
  
  public:

    secondChild() : baseClass("secondChild")
    {
      std::cout << "\n Second Child Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~secondChild() 
    { 
      std::cout << "\n Second Child Destructor" << std::endl;

      this->m1.resize(0, 0);
      this->m2.resize(0, 0);
    }

    void someComputation() override 
    {
      // Some Computation Using Base classes m1 and m2 go here.
      std::cout << "\n Second Child M1 : \n" << this->m1 << "\n M2 : \n" << this->m2 << std::endl;
    }
};

class classIterator
{
  public:
    std::vector< baseClass *> classItr;

    classIterator()
    {
      std::cout << "\n Iterator Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~classIterator() 
    { 
      std::cout << "\n Iterator Destructor" << std::endl;
      for (auto * tLayer : this->classItr) { delete tLayer; }
    }

    template< typename T >
    void onAddClass(T classObj)
    {
      this->classItr.push_back(classObj);
    }

    template<typename inputType_1>
    void onWork(MatrixBase<inputType_1> const & someMat)
    {
      for (auto * tLayer : this->classItr) { tLayer->operator()(someMat); }
    }
};

classIterator onCreateIterator()
{
  classIterator clsItr;

  baseClass * obj1 = new firstChild();
  baseClass * obj2 = new secondChild();

  MatrixXd o1_m1 = MatrixXd::Random(3, 4);
  MatrixXd o1_m2 = MatrixXd::Random(3, 4);

  MatrixXd o2_m1 = MatrixXd::Random(2, 4);
  MatrixXd o2_m2 = MatrixXd::Random(2, 4);

  obj1->onSetData(o1_m1, o1_m2);
  obj2->onSetData(o2_m1, o2_m2);

  clsItr.onAddClass(obj1);
  clsItr.onAddClass(obj2);

  return clsItr;
}

int main()
{
  if (true)
  {
    MatrixXd someMat = MatrixXd::Random(4, 3);
    classIterator clsItr = onCreateIterator();
    clsItr.onWork(someMat);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using `std::unique_ptr`? Then you wouldn't even have to think about it

Comment: Yes, I think unique_ptr might be what I will end up using. This was simply the first approach that came to my mind, I would still like to known how good this solution is for the sake of understanding new and delete functions.